# html table with various column count in each row

Tags: html, html-table

I would to make a table with various and independent column count in each row. for example the first row has 2 column and the 2'nd row has 3 column. I tried this with the following code, but it's wrong:

```
    <table  summary="worker_resume_user_info" style="width:100%">
        <tbody id="2">
        <tr style="border:none">
            <td colspan="12">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                1
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                2
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: 4 + 4 does not equal 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much, you were really close.

You just needed to make sure that your addition is correct. Your two column colspan added must equal your 3 column colspan added. In this example 6+6 = 4+4+4

```
<table border=1 summary="worker_resume_user_info" style="width:100%">
    <tbody id="2">
        <tr style="border:none">
            <td colspan="6">6</td>
            <td colspan="6">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">4</td>
            <td colspan="4">4</td>
            <td colspan="4">4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcjb23jo/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are getting at but this table has 2 columns in the first row and 3 columns in the second row.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Column 1
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            Column 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Column 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Column 2
        </td>
        <td>
            Column 3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```